# Implement Services in Broadcast Receiver notification

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have created a class for showing notifications at particular date and time. This is the source code of the class for creating the notification:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    public static int SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID = 0;



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence from = "Scheduled Training";
        CharSequence message = "Please attend the scheduled training";

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, TextToSpeechScreen.class), 0);

        //OLD CODE

        Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Barclays Scheduled Training", System.currentTimeMillis());

        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
        notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // Play default notification sound
        notifyDetails.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
//      notifyDetails.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
    }
}
```

This is is the method which I am calling from an activity to set the notification at a specific time:

```
// setting alarm

    public void setOneTimeAlarm() {

        // the time set
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();


        // calendar.setTime(model.getStartDate());
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, model.getStartTimeHour());
        // calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, model.getStartTimeMinutes());
        // calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, count);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);


    }
```

Everything is working fine, now I have a requirement to implement **Services** in the **TimeAlarm** class, such that the notifications can be fired from a background process. How should I implement this? Is it possible to send notifications using a background process? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can of course send broadcasts from a (background) service. Was that your question?

Comment: Yes, can you please help me with that?

Comment: You can find further information about how to send broadcasts here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29